# 'Silently' break execution in Visual Studio (without going to source)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, edit-and-continue

[Edit-and-Continue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue-visual-csharp?view=vs-2017) is really handy, but each time I break the execution of my program to begin editing, it either takes me to Program.cs or some core library VS doesn't have symbols for. Is there any way to make VS effectively break, but not navigate me to the currently executing symbols?

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you just want to control which source file comes up. You could place a breakpoint in a file which contains frequently executed code, then that file will appear when the breakpoint is hit. An "onclick" handler is good for this, then you can make it happen whenever you want.

Comment: What I usually do, in order to use the "edit-and-continue" option, is setting a breakpoint at the appropriate lines of code.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, this is what I do for those cases, but oftentimes I find myself needing to edit unrelated code. It's really a desire to use Edit-and-Continue nearly continuously - perfectly doable, just time consuming to keep breaking into unloaded symbols.